# How to display a custom field (variable) in a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to have a shortcode display a value which is a custom field in Wordpress. In this case the variable "prijs".
I have tried lots of solutions on the net and lots more but no luck so far. Can anyone help me ?
Why doesn't this script show anything ? How do i display the custom field "prijs" ?

```
<?php
function showdetails_shortcode( $attr, $content = null ) {
    return <?php $key="prijs"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>
}
add_shortcode('showdetails', 'showdetails_shortcode');
?>
```

Comment: "Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly will lead to unexpected results. This is similar to the way filter functions should behave, in that they should not produce expected side effects from the call, since you cannot control when and where they are called from."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why doesn't this script show anything?*

The provided code shows a couple of syntax errors, of which the most crucial is the re-invocation of `<?php` within a PHP statement.

If `prijs` is a good custom field key for the post where this shortcode is placed, then it should work.

```
function showdetails_shortcode( ) {

   $post_id = get_the_ID();

//either output the value or let us know the code is working but the value has not been found
   $output = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'prijs', true) ? get_post_meta( $post_id, 'prijs', true) : 'NO CUSTOM VALUE FOUND' ;

   return $output;

}

add_shortcode('showdetails', 'showdetails_shortcode');
```

---

Responding to a comment, here's a version with two fields and tabular output, keeping in mind that there would be cleaner (more flexible and parsimonious) ways to derive the variables and produce the output for a larger number of fields.

```
function showdetails_shortcode( ) {

   $post_id = get_the_ID();

   //extract the field values
   $field1 = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'prijs', true) ? get_post_meta( $post_id, 'prijs', true) : 'PRIJS NOT FOUND';
   $field2 = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'prijs2', true) ? get_post_meta( $post_id, 'prijs2', true) : 'PRIJS2 NOT FOUND';

   //prepare html table output
   $output = '<table><tbody>'; 
   $output .= '<tr><td>' . $field1 . '</td></tr>';
   $output .= '<tr><td>' . $field2 . '</td></tr>'; 
   $output .= '</tbody></table>';

   //return the html    
   return $output;

}

add_shortcode('showdetails', 'showdetails_shortcode');
```

Comment: Brilliant ! It works. Thanks very much. You saved me a lot of frustration and time :-)

Comment: But it doesn't work with 2 (wanted to build a whole table with all 30 custom fields)
-----
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$cp_prijs = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'prijs', true) ? get_post_meta( $post_id, 'prijs', true) : 'NO CUSTOM VALUE FOUND' ;
return $cp_prijs;
-----
$cp_merk = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'merk', true) ? get_post_meta( $post_id, 'merk', true) : 'NO CUSTOM VALUE FOUND' ;
return $cp_merk;

Comment: You can only `return` once for your shortcode function. As with any other PHP function, `return` stops processing if/when encountered. I've added more to the answer, but I'm not recommending you merely expand it to handle 30 fields. On the other hand, if you can make it work, you might have to go with it at least until after you've done more PHP study. Also, since I answered the initial question, please mark my answer as good!

Comment: The answer is not good. It was super fast and completely correct. I'm very pleased. Thank you very much !